# Custom email verification – cannot set emailVerified

Tags: php, email, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, mandrill

I'm trying to implement **custom email verification** for user sign up. The default one only sends plain text messages, but we want to send HTML formatted ones.

The current approach:

1. Using Cloud Code, a function `Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Parse.User"…` sets a generated token in the user's '`confirmationToken`' field
2. The same function sends a formatted email using *MailChimp*'s [Mandrill Cloud Module](http://Mandrill%20Cloud%20Module) service to the user, including a confirmation link with the `confirmationToken` like this http://www.our-website.com/confirm_email.php?confirmationToken=`confirmationToken`
3. The User clicks on the link, our website gets the token through a HTTP GET request
4. The website runs [Parse PHP SDK](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk) and queries the user database to get the user with the `confirmationToken` field's value that matches the token from the request
5. If the user is found, we attempt to set the `emailVerified` field to `true`…

Now here's the problem. The `emailVerified` field seems to be protected. Trying to set it will give you a `ParseException` 'InvalidKeyName' (**105**). Now, I could just use another field, but the problem is that we had set up the default Parse email verification previously, and our apps are looking for that value in `emailVerified`. Users already signed up with the default email verification, and we cannot just change it because the apps are deployed.

Is there any way we can set the `emailVerified` field? 
Can anyone think of a solution that will also work for apps that are already checking for this field, even though in the future we'd have to set another one?
Is the field still protected if you disable email verification (right now it is still enabled)?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `emailVerified` attribute cannot be set, even using the master key.  The only alternative is to create a custom verified attribute to go along with the custom verification logic.

The approach I'd take would be this:

1. build and test the new scheme, using the new field
2. run a migration that populates the new attribute with the users' `emailVerified`
3. invoke that same logic in `afterSave` for any `Parse.User`
4. revise the client to check the new attribute

I realize that step 4. violates a premise of the question, but your app must designed under the premise that the client can and will be revised.  If its not this issue, it will be another.  Operating conditions will change, and so must your client.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What to best approach to design a client that can be revised?
Right now I either break the app for the existing user sign up, or I have to send verification emails twice for new users. I guess I should add some Parse Class that enables or disables features in the app in relation to their version?

Comment: Can you just replace the client with one that signs up via the new process?  What kind of client is it?

Comment: It's a native iPhone and Android app, so I am just wondering how I could maintain compatibility when people won't update the app all at the same time. I'm not even able to give my users an error message in the sign up process for the old app. I was just hoping you could give me some more specific design strategies as you said _your app must designed under the premise that the client can and will be revised_.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to add that we've deployed an app on Parse 60 days ago averaging 2,000 new users a week with email verification required. Our users are largely government (lots of .gov's). We spend hours each day handling support tickets in Zendesk around users not receiving the verification link. The support is crushing us.

I realize the intent of locking the field, but if I get an email from the user, that's verification enough from me and it would save us so much time to toggle emailVerified to true.

Please reconsider letting developers make this decision on their own.

Comment: +1 Our custom solution would have worked probably the same way as the default parse.com one. And if they would have HTML email, we wouldn't even have to do this.
By the way, I think you can set the emailVerified field manually in the database anyhow.

Comment: @JulianVogels unfortunately you can't. When you try to toggle `emailVerified` true/false Parse throws the error: "Users cannot set emailVerified field"

Comment: Yes, you're right, it doesn't update. You can toggle it, and it even sets the value… I didn't notice the alert on the bottom at first.